# How do easily filter CSV data in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I am dealing with a CSV file(approx 500 lines). Is there a way to select data from this file with filters. I know I can do this in ruby by parsing the csv and using select/find methods But I am looking for a simpler syntax. I don't want to write methods to process each of the below queries. Any gem that would allow me do these queries? I am looking for a non-Rails solution as I am writing a plain ruby script.

e.g.

```
csv.find_rows(where: {'GENDER' => 'MALE'}.count
```

or

```
csv.find_rows(where: {'GENDER' => 'MALE', 'SALARY' >= 10000 }
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't think you need a gem here:

```
csv.select { |row| row['GENDER'] == 'MALE' }
csv.select { |row| row['GENDER'] == 'MALE' || row['SALARY'] >= 10000 }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I need to process this csv for multiple data queries hence I am looking for a solution out of the box without having to write what you suggested above.

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean `out of the box?` Is 2 lines of code not `out of the box` enough for you? :)

Comment: Andrey, what I mean is some gem/helper that allows me to use the syntax I specified. It's 2 lines of code but I need to filter data multiple times and using various filter criteria.

Comment: @Rahul I agree with Andrey, you have in any case to specify your conditions and select syntax is not so more verbose than the one you provide. I mean, no need for a gem.

Comment: @Rahul there is no such gem because it does not even make sense to create one with such functionality. Think of it - you are looking for some sort of activerecord syntax while saying you want a non-Rails solution. If you want non-Rails solution - use Ruby, it is there for you with simple ready-to-go methods. Your needs are elementary and I do not see how would any gem simplify it